# 2 of Same method Names in Controller wired up to Routes with Web API

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api2

It's been a while since I've done some controller code in MVC.  But is it possible to have overloads of the same method name in your controller such as:

(this is pseudo code, it's not perfect)

[HttpGet]
Get()

[HttpGet]
Get(int id)

I think you can right?  You differentiate that with the route pattern right?  Just rechecking, I am working with WCF and I just wondering if I could do this in MVC and I think I could in the past, just don't recall.  WCF bitches when you have 2 overloads with method name Get when using WebGet and it's bugging the hell out of me...I don't like that.

Comment: Yes i think this is possible in web api and you don't need to specify HttpGet attribute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

es you can have overloads but each extra overload has to be marked with the `[ActionName]` attribute. Otherwise the controller will get confused and throw a `AmbiguousMatchException` at runtime, but the overloads will compile.

Here is an example with overloads added a Default Home Controller:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    // Default Action method.
    // Url: /Home
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        ViewBag.Message = "jump-start your ASP.NET MVC application.";

        return View();
    }

    // Url: /Home/About
    public ActionResult About()
    {
        ViewBag.Message = "Your app description page.";

        return View();
    }

    // Url: /Home/AboutByInt/3
    [ActionName("AboutByInt")]
    public ActionResult About(int id)
    {
        ViewBag.Message = "Your app description page. The Id is: " + id;

        return View();
    }
}
```

An alternative is to use nullable arguments, that can supplied or not supplied to the Action method:

```
// Url: /Home/Contact
public ActionResult Contact(int? id)
{
    if (id == null)
    {
        // Page was accessed by url: /Home/Contact
        ViewBag.Message = "id is null";
    }
    else
    {
        // Page was accessed by url: /Home/Contact/[int]
        ViewBag.Message = "id is : " + id;
    }

    return View();
}
```

Comment: right but point is you CAN have multiple Get() methods with diff sigs.  Good point on the nullable but that was just pseudo code above with mine.  My question and point is, you CAN do this with the Web API and MVC..in your case you're saying use nullable int to keep the route engine from getting confused

Comment: Ok I misunderstood you. Yes you can have multiple get methods (Actions) in a controller but only one default Action method. Assuming you are using default routing the Action method names will correspond to the routing url. I will edit my answer to be a little bit better.

Answer (score 0):

Use attribute routing.

Add this to your WebApiConfig file:

```
config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();
```

You can then use attributes to specify your routes and required parameters.

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("/api/mycontroller")]
public IHttpActionResult Get()
{
    var myQuery = {your query};
    return Ok(myQuery);
}

[HttpGet]
[Route("/api/mycontroller/{id:int}")]
public IHttpActionResult Get(int id)
{
    var myQuery = {your query};
    return Ok(myQuery);
}
```

You can shorten your route attributes by putting a RoutePrefix on your controller.

```
[RoutePrefix("api/mycontroller")]
public class MyControllerController : WebApiController
{
    ...
}
```

Then you can cut out that portion on your action routes.

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("")]
public IHttpActionResult Get()
{
    ...
}

[HttpGet]
[Route("{id:int}")]
public IHttpActionResult Get(int id)
{
    ...
}
```

Also, you don't NEED to specify the data type in your route parameter:

```
[Route("{id}")]
```

I just like strongly typed stuff.